# Calculate The Proper X and Y Coordinate

Tags: java

I have a class called `Tile`, the constructor takes an integer that represents the tile's 
type. You can load a tileset ( via `loadTileset()` ) which initalizes the fields -

- tileset
- numOfTiles
- tileWidth
- tileHeight

My question is, in the constructor, depending on the type variable. How do I figure out the proper x and y cooridates to uses in the `getSubimage()` method.

[image]

So for example, if `type` is set to the value 2, I'd want to get the x and y position of the upper-left corner of number two.

```
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Tile {

private int type;
private BufferedImage tile;

// tileset attributes
public static BufferedImage tileset;
public static int numOfTiles;

public static int tileWidth;
public static int tileHeight;

// constructor
public Tile(int type) {

    // contruct tile
    this.type = type;
    // ...
    tile = tileset.getSubimage(0, 0, tileWidth, tileHeight);
}

public static void loadTileset(String filename, Dimension tileSize) {

    // load tileset
    try {
        tileset = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // initalize attributes
    tileWidth  = (int) tileSize.getWidth ();
    tileHeight = (int) tileSize.getHeight();

    numOfTiles = (tileset.getWidth() / tileWidth) * (tileset.getHeight() / tileHeight);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
int x = type % 3;
int y = type / 3;
```

Comment: the formula for finding the width is perfect, the other is not working properly with different sized maps.